# Spring, beans and enum's valueOf

Tags: java, spring, enums, javabeans

When calling Spring's "Validate" from Eclipse, I get a lot of errors when I want to get back an enum using Enum's implicit *"valueOf"* method.

For example:

```
<bean id="docFamily" class="...DocFamily" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg>
      <value>LOGY</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

has Eclipse telling me:

> Non-static factory method 'valueOf'
>   with 1 arguments not found in factory
>   bean class ...

However as I understand it from the documentation:

> BeanWrapperImpl supports JDK 1.5 enums
>   and old-style enum classes: String
>   values will be treated as enum value
>   names

So the above should work right? (btw is 'constructor-arg' the correct tag in that case, shouldn't it be some 'method-arg'?).

Why is Eclipse/Spring's "Validate" giving me that error message?

Answer (score 5):

`Enum.valueOf()` has two arguments:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)
```

Therefore the desired definition may look like this:

```xml
<bean id="docFamily" class="java.lang.Enum" factory-method="valueOf">
     <constructor-arg index = "0"><value>...DocFamily</value></constructor-arg>
     <constructor-arg index = "1"><value>LOGY</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

However, something like this can be a more elegant solution:

```xml
<util:constant id = "docFamily" static-field = "...DocFamily.LOGY" />
```

Comment: I agree, but OP's not trying to use `java.lang.Enum.valueOf()`. I rather understand it's `DocFamily.valueOf()` which is tried to be called.

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki: but DocFamily is an Enum

Answer (score 1):

I just tried using it like this:

```xml
<bean id="docFamily" class="...DocFamily" factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="LOGY"/>
</bean>
```

and it worked like charm. Does it works for you?